# What’s wrong with my gardenia

Tags: leaves

I received this gardenia for Mother’s Day and it was beautiful.  I repotted and placed it my patio where it received morning sun and watered nearly every day.  The leaves began to turn yellow and when the temperature was to be in the 90’s I brought it in to the house.  The soil was very moist so I have not watered for a few weeks hoping it would come back.  It did flower a couple times on the patio but they quickly turned brown and fell off.  Have I watered too much, not enough?  Did it get too hot?  I’m at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: Hi Roxanne,  can you add a picture?

Comment: My default *guess* when somone says they water a plant every day is that it's *probably* being overwatered.

Comment: Gardenias are very temperamental, but worth it for the heavenely aroma. Heat is no problem for such a Deep South plant. But it is a shade lover there. And you stopped watering for weeks and wonder what's wrong?